# Get iframe src via xpath

Tags: xml, iframe, xpath, web-scraping

I'm trying to extract the `iframe src` from [here](http://devour.com/video/obama-throws-shade/):
`<div class="video-wrapper">
<iframe src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/6KAG7kltnuE?    autohide=1&amp;color=white&amp;fs=1&amp;autoplay=0&amp;iv_load_policy=3&amp;rel=0&amp;modestbranding=1&amp;showinfo=0&amp;hd=1" frameborder="0" width="940" height="526" allowfullscreen></iframe>                                                             </div>`

my current XPath is off and is `//div[@class="video-wrapper"]/iframe/[@src]`

Answer (score 1):

Try this XPath:

```
//div[@class="video-wrapper"]/iframe/@src
```